# str_replace doesn't replace all occurrences, but gsub does?

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub, stringr

I am trying to remove brackets from a string like the one below.

```
library(stringr)

x <- "(Verhoeff,1937)"

str_replace(string = x, pattern = "(\\()|(\\))", replacement = "")
[1] "Verhoeff,1937)"

gsub(pattern = "(\\()|(\\))", replacement = "", x = x)
[1] "Verhoeff,1937"
```

`str_replace` doesn't seem to find the closing bracket?
Any ideas why?

Comment: `sub` ≈ `str_replace`; `gsub` ≈ `str_replace_all` (the “g” stands for “global”).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It only matches the first occurency, whereas `gsub` does it all. Use `str_replace_all` instead:

```
str_replace(string = "aa", pattern = "a", replacement = "b") # only first

str_replace_all(string = "aa", pattern = "a", replacement = "b") # all
```

Comment: that is, `str_replace` is `sub` whereas `str_replace_all` is `gsub`.